# no simple json module in python 3.7

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I am trying import `'simplejson'`module into in my pycharm project. It is throwing an error saying that `import simplejson as json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'` 
I installed simple json in the terminal using `pip3 install simplejson`.
I have tried not renaming it `as json` but that didn't work.

Comment: If you run simply `python3` on the terminal to get a python console, then try `import simplejson`, does it work?

Comment: There's not much point to use this since you mentioned you're on Python 3.7.  The json library included with Python *is* simplejson for all practical purposes (simplejson is an externally maintained development version of the same code).

Comment: @BenWhaley doesn't seem to throw any errors. so i perfume that means its working.

Comment: Check that the python executable is in the same path as the pip3 executable. Pycharm creates a virtual environment by default and this means pip modules are installed into by default instead of on a system level. You have then 2 options, install simplejson with the help of pycharm or use the pip inside the venv (you can easily search how) to install the module.